# pSQL array field only

Tags: mysql, arrays, prestashop, sql-insert

I'm trying to INSERT a big ARRAY, but it breaks because one of the fields (product_name) because of the sigle quote "'".

How can i pSQL only the product_name field before inserting the array into database?

This is what my database looks like (its a prestashop order_detail table)

```
[75] => Array
    (
        [id_order_detail] => 76
        [id_order] => 23
        [id_order_invoice] => 13
        [id_warehouse] => 0
        [id_shop] => 1
        [product_id] => 5191
        [product_attribute_id] => 0
        [id_parent] => 5191
        [parent_reference] => 0
        [item_position] => 0
        [product_name] => AMIX MR POPPER'S NOCAMIX WHITE CHOCO CREAM 275G
        [product_quantity] => 1
        [product_quantity_in_stock] => 1
        [product_quantity_refunded] => 0
        [product_quantity_return] => 0
        [product_quantity_reinjected] => 0
        [product_price] => 8.363636
        [reduction_percent] => 10.00
        [reduction_amount] => 0.000000
        [reduction_amount_tax_incl] => 0.000000
        [reduction_amount_tax_excl] => 0.000000
        [group_reduction] => 0.00
        [product_quantity_discount] => 9.380000
        [product_ean13] => 
        [product_upc] => 647
        [product_reference] => L655
        [product_supplier_reference] => 
        [product_weight] => 0.000000
        [tax_computation_method] => 0
        [tax_name] => 
        [tax_rate] => 0.000
        [ecotax] => 0.000000
        [ecotax_tax_rate] => 0.000
        [discount_quantity_applied] => 0
        [download_hash] => 
        [download_nb] => 0
        [download_deadline] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [total_price_tax_incl] => 8.280000
        [total_price_tax_excl] => 7.530000
        [unit_price_tax_incl] => 8.280000
        [unit_price_tax_excl] => 7.530000
        [total_shipping_price_tax_incl] => 0.000000
        [total_shipping_price_tax_excl] => 0.000000
        [purchase_supplier_price] => 5.150000
        [original_product_price] => 8.363636
        [original_wholesale_price] => 0.000000
    )

[76] => Array
    (
```

And this is how i'm doing the insert.

Db::getInstance()->insert('order_detail', $response);

While the $response is the whole array.
As you can all see, i'm a newbie; any help is appreciated.

Thanks alot!

Comment: try to edit the `$response` variable with `$response['product_name'] = pSQL($response['product_name'])` before the insert.

Comment: $response['product_name'] ain't working because its a multidimensional array (i think). It throws "Notice: Undefined index: id_order_detail". Doing $response[0]['product_name'] works, but it only inserts the first line. I'll have to do a foreach i think

Answer (score 0):

You can write the whole query using **Db::getInstance()->execute** so you can escape the single fields, or you have to necessarily clean your data inside $response array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple trick. With this function you can do it easily, and it will work in more cases.

```
Db::getInstance()->insert('order_detail', mypSQL($response));

function mypSQL($var)
{
    if (is_array($var)) {
        foreach ($var as $key => $val) {
            $var[$key] = mypSQL($val);
        }
    } elseif (is_string($var)) {
        $var = pSQL($var);
    }

    return $var;
}
```